# Generic class and implements type

Tags: typescript

I think I miss something big about typescript, here is my current code:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from "node:events";

interface IService extends EventEmitter {
  actions: string[];
  events?: string[];
}

// I know this is not some valid typescript here, but I just want to express the fact that
// createService expects a class type that inherits from EventEmitter AND 
// implements the IService interface
function createService<S extends IService>(ServiceClass: S) {
  const s = new ServiceClass();
  console.log(s.actions);
  console.log(s.events);
  
  return s;
}


class MyService extends EventEmitter implements IService {
  actions = ["action1", "action2"];
  events = ["event1", "event2"];

  action1(str: string) {
    this.emit("event1");
  }
  action2(num: number) {
    return num;
  }
}

const service = createService(MyService)
```

My issue is described in the comment above

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2NkmDGdKOAXzgDMoIQ4AiTCAE3QC50NsBnWgbgFgAUIODYi5AIYBjdHACSAZSKpg0uOgAehTI04oOOPASKJBcOFJjAImTizicYUEQHMA2gF1%20As%20ywxOAPx2Dk6Ybp6CJIKCAPQxcnAA1gwA7nAwABbAutlwDPCc1DKo4gA2wIzpAJ5g6JySTmDwGUToADRwAEYArvCycABW3Q5wKeLY6RBq6mBQdbqZMhKS8JniMLHxDejr6IpQyqoatSu64nCSpeKcCzUya-AiLU7%20FFQ0aH64%20ITEAIIAOQAInBNnBQGBSugQH4Fi05PtDjIRL9luhBORupgVlZMBc5rtESp0AAeeTTLQ6BFKYkAPgAFETpABhK43OzyACUJm8F2sI10AF48ug0kz0Kzrpx6ZyvGZJPyIFCAHSlCDOemcZUWXGcWWmPk2JXoVXqzXK3xcfW8g1zGDdKB4zheKJCN2XKVwACyVXFFKwVM%202G%20RmIEKhMK41IOxJ5Zh1-LgwtctATmAAjLQOqmcdYAEy0CK8y2vZO0EuZ7MlgtFg1p9OaxzBRwubkIA1mTLZC2Genl-SZ61mV3x3OYPP0zDdEB2KcgTpENsduB2h14udy0iRaICBU2Ao01TC7aEw-oek%208WcoA)

Comment: You are looking for a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL3E2N).  This is almost certainly a duplicate, but if I can't find an appropriate question I might write up an answer here.